# Empty tag after XSL Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

Here is my XSL transformation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:Message="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"
xmlns:BankPositivePay="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/BankPositivePay">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Header>
      <records>
        <record>
          <xsl:value-of select="/BankPositivePay/BankAccountTable/AccountNum"/>
        </record>
      </records>
    </Header>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the input xml file is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
  <Header>
    <MessageId>{A604C46E-F3E3-4BCB-9F7A-E8FD8749A7FC}</MessageId>
    <Action>http://tempuri.org/BankPositivePayService/find</Action>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
      <BankPositivePay xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/BankPositivePay">
        <BankAccountTable class="entity">
          <AccountID>USA OPER</AccountID>
          <AccountNum>34567</AccountNum>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <LedgerDimension>
            <MainAccount xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/sharedtypes">110110</MainAccount>
          </LedgerDimension>
          <BankChequeTable class="entity">
            <AccountID>USA OPER</AccountID>
            <AmountCur>3500.00</AmountCur>
            <ChequeNum>1132</ChequeNum>
            <ChequeStatus>Payment</ChequeStatus>
            <RecipientAccountNum>1001</RecipientAccountNum>
            <TransDate>2013-08-16</TransDate>
            <VendTable class="entity">
              <Currency>USD</Currency>
              <DefaultDimension>
                <Values xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/sharedtypes">
                  <Value>
                    <Name>CustomDepartment</Name>
                    <Value>060</Value>
                  </Value>
                </Values>
              </DefaultDimension>
              <VendGroup>10</VendGroup>
            </VendTable>
            <CompanyInfo xsi:type="AxdEntity_CompanyInfo_CompanyInfo" class="entity" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <DataArea>ceu</DataArea>
            </CompanyInfo>
          </BankChequeTable>
        </BankAccountTable>
      </BankPositivePay>
    </MessageParts>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

The problem is I am getting the output as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Header xmlns:Message="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message" xmlns:BankPositivePay="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/BankPositivePay">
  <records>
    <record></record>
  </records>
</Header>
```

The record element is empty although it should return AccountNum 34567. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues with your select expression:

1. You're not using namespaces in your path.
2. You're not locating the node you want

The namespace issue comes up very often here.  Every step of an XPath selector that targets a node with a non-empty namespace URI *must be prefixed* (if you are targeting it with a name selector).

If you change the expression

```
<xsl:value-of select="/BankPositivePay/BankAccountTable/AccountNum"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="//BankPositivePay:BankPositivePay/BankPositivePay:BankAccountTable/BankPositivePay:AccountNum"/>
```

then your output will be

```
<Header xmlns:Message="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message" xmlns:BankPositivePay="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/BankPositivePay">
    <records>
        <record>34567</record>
    </records>
</Header>
```

The `//` is needed because the element you're targeting is not at the root.  `//` is generally avoided because it is "expensive"; how exactly you target that node depends on your requirements.

Comment: ...at this point it's worth mentioning that namespace prefixes are freely selectable. Instead of `xmlns:BankPositivePay="..."` using `xmlns:bpp="..."` would make for more readable XPath.

Comment: @Tomalak, very true.  this uses the declarations that were already in the OP's document, but I would definitely use shorter prefixes.

Comment: Additionally, as of XSLT 2.0 one could use `xpath-default-namespace="..."` to work without repeating most prefixes the rest of the time. Using `exclude-result-prefixes` is a good idea in any case.